# Remote method invocation port in use

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I have created a Server, Client kind of program with RMI. But whenever I run my Server after starting the rmiregistry from command prompt, the port already in use error is thrown. Its only me who started the rmiregistry. I have checked it from netstat.

Server Code:

```
public class Server implements Runnable, Linker{


private static Server server = null;
    private static Linker l = null;
    private String name = null;
    public Server(){}

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;               
    }  
    public void run(){
        while(!("Andy").equalsIgnoreCase(name)){

        }
    }
    public static void createStub(){
        try{
            server = new Server();
            l = (Linker) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 1099);

            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
            registry.bind("Link", l);
            System.out.println("Ready");
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                       
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        createStub();
        Thread t = new Thread(server);

    }
}
```

Client Code:

```
public class Client implements Runnable{


private Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    private Linker linker = null;

    public void loadStub(){
        try{
            Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(1099);
            linker = (Linker) registry.lookup("Link");

        }catch(Exception e){

        }
    }
    public void run(){
        String ip = null;
        while(sc.hasNext()&&!(ip = sc.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase(":q")){
            try {
                linker.setName(ip);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String...args){
        Client client = new Client();
        client.loadStub();
        Thread t = new Thread(client);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1099; nested exception is: 
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `rmiregistry` is using port 1099 in its process so you can't use it in yours. Either:

1. Start the registry in the same process, via `LocateRegistry.createRegistry()` (preferred).
2. Export your object on a different port.
3. Start the `rmiregistry` on a different port other than 1099.

Comment: That was the problem in my case. I figured it out and when I was about to post here, I found your reply. netstat -aon shows where it is listening. In this case its listening on all interfaces.

Answer (score 47):

If you're using macOS, you can stop port following as:

First thing you need to find the PID_number: `lsof -i :1099`

And then kill that port: `kill -9 PID_number`

Comment: fwiw -9 is basically a 'force quit'

Comment: No. This will just kill the RMI Registry, which is needed. You have to find the underlying problem, not just shoot everything in sight.

Answer (score 7):

Use this Server code -

```
Registry registry = null;
try {
    registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(52365);//use any no. less than 55000
    registry.list();
    // This call will throw an exception if the registry does not already exist
}
catch (RemoteException e) { 
    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(52365);
}
```

Comment: Why less than 55000? The port also has to be > 1024 for most people. It would be much better to attempt the creation first, then if that fails do getRegistry)). Your way has a timing window problem.

Comment: Is it possible to make without exceptions? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14982760/897090

Comment: @Lescott As I said in the question you quoted, no.

Answer (score 0):

Re-check if the port 1099 is not used by any other process or user or start the rmiregistry on some other port.

Answer (score 0):

Use ps -aef |grep rmiregistry.
find the pid which rmiregistry use.
Kill the pid
Den run the server again...!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
lsof -P | grep ':1099' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```