# Is it possible to manually check LocateRegistry existing?

Tags: java, exception, rmi

I [have found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8338852/897090) a safe way to get `LocateRegistry` (even if the registry does not already exist).

```
Registry registry = null;
try {
    registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(52365);
    registry.list();
    // This call will throw an exception if the registry does not already exist
}
catch (RemoteException e) { 
    registry = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(52365);
}
```

Is it possible to firstly check registry existence and use `getRegistry` or `createRegistry` in accordance with the result of the check?

Comment: No. If there is an error in the function you will need to catch it and react accordingly.

Comment: @mercutio I don't try to fully avoid exceptions. But I want avoid unnecessary calling of `getRegistry` when it doesn't exist. I've update the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to firstly check registry existence and use getRegistry or createRegistry in accordance with the result of the check?

Certainly. Just try the `createRegistry()` first; catch the `ExportException`, which means it's already running, and do the `getRegistry()` unconditionally.

> I want avoid unnecessary calling of getRegistry when it doesn't exist

That's not a valid concern. It is a virtually cost-free call. No network activity.